# Function to Create a Zigzag Array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, function, zigzag, zigzag-encoding

I'm trying to create an array of *positive* and *negative* integers, representing distances *north* and *south* of a location - I need to see the elements of the array in *zigzag* order.

This means that the *largest* member appears first, the *smallest* member appears second, and the remaining elements alternate between the *larger* members decreasing from the *largest* and the *smaller* members increasing from the *smallest*.

I.e. the array [1, 3, 6, 9, -3] becomes [9, -3, 6, 1, 3].

I'm trying to complete the function `wiggleArrangeArray`, which takes one argument, an integer array of n integers.

**Required Input Format, Constraints, and Output Format**
[image]

I'm not sure how to say

"if the item in the array is larger than the other items in the array, display it first."

"if the item is smaller than the other items in the array, display it second."

"then alternate between the next largest numbers, and the next smallest numbers"

```
def wiggleArrangeArray(intArr):
    for i in intArr
        #if i > other items in intArr
        #display that i at index value 0
        #if i < other items in intArr
        #display that i at index value 1
        #if i < i at index value 0 and > other items in intArr, display it next
        #if i > i at index value 1 and < other items in intArr, display it next
        #repeat last two lines for continuing values
```

Please help if possible. [Here's a link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-array-into-zig-zag-fashion/) to the solution in C++ but I need it in Python. Thanks.

**Edit**: The function needs to work with the following tests:

```
f = open(os.environ["OUTPUT_PATH"], "w")

_intArr_cnt = int(raw_input())
_intArr_i=0
_intARR = []
while _intArr_i < _intArr_cnt:
    _intArr_item = int(raw_input());
    _intArr.append(_intArr_item)
    _intArr_i+=1

res = wiggleArrangeArray(_intArr);
for res_cur in res:
    f.write( str(res_cur) + "\n" )

f.close()
```

Comment: You already have a solution and wants people to write it in python for you?

Comment: I've never worked with C++ ...I don't know how to convert between languages.

Comment: @HappyHands31: I never worked much with C++ either, usually it's not really a problem to *read* programs in languages you haven't seen yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The altered C++ code

> **Note** the algorithm you provided **does** calculate some sort of zigzag, but **it is not the zigzag you are looking for**. For future reference I will leave it here.
>
> In the C++ code you provided, they only look for a sequences that satisfies a < b > c < d > e < f, you are looking however for a sequence with the 1-max, 1-min, 2-max, 2-min,...

Your link provides you a solution which you can copy nearly verbatim in Python. You only define a `swap` function:

```
def swap(arr,i,j):
    t = arr[i]
    arr[i] = arr[j]
    arr[j] = t
```

Next you can simply modify the code:

```
def zigZag(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    # Flag true indicates relation "<" is expected,
    # else ">" is expected.  The first expected relation
    # is "<"
    flag = True

    i = 0
    while i<= n-2:
        if (flag):  # "<" relation expected
            # If we have a situation like A > B > C,
            # we get A > B < C by swapping B and C
            if arr[i] > arr[i+1]:
                swap(arr,i,i+1)
        else: # ">" relation expected
            # If we have a situation like A < B < C,
            #  we get A < C > B by swapping B and C
            if arr[i] < arr[i+1]:
                swap(arr,i,i+1)
        flag = not flag # flip flag
        i += 1
```

Mind that this is rather *un-Pythonic*, so you can simply improve it like:

```
def swap(arr,i,j):
    arr[i],arr[j] = arr[j],arr[i]

def zigZag(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    for i in range(len(arr)-1):
        if not i&1:
            if arr[i] > arr[i+1]:
                swap(arr,i,i+1)
        elif arr[i] < arr[i+1]:
            swap(arr,i,i+1)
    return arr
```

Here *tuple assignment* is used to swap elements in the list, a `range` is used to iterate over the indices, we can furthermore use an `elif` instead of an `if` in an `else`, and for I've abandoned the `flag` by using a modulo check.

## Your zigzag function

You can simply solve the problem by sorting the list, and using two pointers that each time emit the most left, the most right and walk towards each other. In other words something like:

```
def zigZag(arr):
    srt = sorted(arr)
    left = 0
    right = len(srt)-1
    result = []
    while left < right:
        result.append(srt[right])
        right -= 1
        if left < right:
            result.append(srt[left])
            left += 1
    return result
```

Comment: unfortunately I'm not able to get it to work with the test (see edit) and I did replace zigZag with wiggleArrangeArray. I'm getting a Traceback error:

File "solution.py" line 33 in <module>
   for res_cur in res:

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: @HappyHands31: can you perhaps *provide* the traceback?

Comment: @HappyHands31: that's because you copy pasted it the wrong way, and **the algorithm you provided is simply wrong as well**: I've tested the C++ algorithm online [see here](http://code.geeksforgeeks.org/Zrfr2b) and it produced the wrong results.

Comment: @HappyHands31: is this a running programming contest you aim to solve? Bit unethical in that case to ask your questions on SO...

Comment: It's not a programming contest, it was for a class test. We were allowed to consult this website as a resource.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133588/discussion-between-happyhands31-and-willem-van-onsem).

Answer (score 0):

Here Python implementation example.

1. Sort your data in reversed order (9, 6, 3, 1, -3)
2. Split by two lists (9, 6) (3, 1, -3)
3. Iterate over both (using zip_longest) first one from start, second in reverse order (9, -3), (6, 1) (None, 3)
4. Unpack tuples created by zip_longest (chain(*zip...)) so you get iterable data (9, -3, 6, 1, None, 3)
5. Remove None value in case if the list has an odd number of elements (if x is not None)

Example:

```
from itertools import zip_longest, chain


def zig_zag_array(data):
    data = sorted(data)
    mid = len(data) // 2
    return [
        x for x in chain(*zip_longest(data[mid:][::-1], data[:mid])) if x is not None
    ]
```

Test:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = [1, 3, 6, 9, -3]
    expected = [9, -3, 6, 1, 3]
    output = zig_zag_array(data)
    assert output == expected, f"Odd length: {output=}"

    data = [1, 3, 6, 9, -3, 0]
    expected = [9, -3, 6, 0, 3, 1]
    output = zig_zag_array(data)
    assert output == expected, f"Even length: {output=}"
    print("PASSED")
```